# MySQL auto generate following number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are 4 columns in my relationship table:

1. ID
2. CID - course id
3. LID - related lesson unique id
4. course_based_id - explanation below

There are bunch of lessons and courses with unique id's in another tables called `lessons` and `courses`. This table is, asociation table between them. Basically it assigns unique lesson id to unique course id. But.. There is need for course based id of lesson. I mean, for example lets take a look at first and second rows from screenshot

[image]

Lid 1 is course 2's first lesson, lid 3 is course 2's second lesson... And so on. So if I insert cid 2, lid 128 it must third lesson of course 2.

Now, the problem is, I want to auto generate this number while insert:

```
$q="INSERT INTO `courses-lessons` (`cid`, `lid`) VALUES (?,?)";
```

but have no idea how to do it. Some MySQL function? or something inside query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using MyISAM engine to store this table, this can be done relatively easy: you just define the fields this way:

```
cid INT NOT NULL,
course_based_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
PRIMARY KEY (cid, course_based_id)
```

Then any `INSERT` will automatically assign a new (+1) value for `course_based_id` based on `cid`. Here's a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/473f2/1) illustrating this concept.

You can find more info about it in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Unfortunately, there's no such mechanism in InnoDB engine. So perhaps you can get away with the following routine (it's a pseudocode, there are some nuances):

```
1) lock table for writing; 
2) @x = SELECT MAX(course_based_id) WHERE cid = %cid_to_be_inserted%;
3) INSERT (..., course_based_id) VALUES (..., @x + 1);
4) unlock table;
```

I'd suggest checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369984/1229023); it's for PostgreSQL, not MySQL, but describes one possible implementation in some details.

**UPDATE:** Here's an example of actual set of queries implementing that behaviour:

```
CREATE TABLE tx
  (id INT NOT NULL, cid INT NOT NULL, lid INT NOT NULL,
   course_based_id INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE KEY (cid, course_based_id)
);

LOCK TABLE tx WRITE, tx AS t READ;

INSERT INTO tx (id, cid, lid, course_based_id)
  SELECT 2, 2, 1, 
         1 + COALESCE(
               (SELECT MAX(course_based_id) 
                  FROM tx AS t 
                 WHERE cid = 2), 
             0);

 INSERT INTO tx (id, cid, lid, course_based_id)
   SELECT 3, 2, 3, 
          1 + COALESCE(
                (SELECT MAX(course_based_id) 
                  FROM tx AS t WHERE cid = 2),
              0);

 UNLOCK TABLES;
```

As you see, there's no direct calculation of the next `course_based_id` value, yet we got the sequence here.

Comment: There is 1 auto_increment column in table. I can't define second.

Comment: Can I change it's engine from INNODB to myisam without data lose? I have foreign keys related with this table too BTW

Comment: are you there? Why don't you answer to my comments?

Comment: @epic_syntax: If you need Foreign Keys, then you can't use MyISAM, so this trick will not work.

Comment: @ypercube so what do you suggest?

Comment: I get all except locking tables. I'm using prepared statements in PHP. How to lock table before operating?

Comment: [LOCK TABLE t WRITE, t AS t1 READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html). I'll try to create some example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want referential integrity (Foreign Keys) you are using InnoDB, so the (nice) MyISAM trick does not work.

What you can do is generate those `course_based_id` during the inserts into the table.

Write a - not so complex - procedure that does the inserts and allow no other code to insert into this table - excpet through this procedure. You'll also need a procedure for the updates (and one for the deletes, if you mind having gaps in this course_based_id).

So, instead of the:

```
INSERT INTO courses_lessons 
  (cid, lid) 
VALUES 
  ( ?cid, ?lid ) ;
```

you'll have, enclosed in a stored procedure to catch any errors (duplicates, etc):

```
INSERT INTO courses_lessons 
  (cid, lid, course_based_id) 
SELECT 
  ?cid, ?lid, 
  1 + COALESCE( ( SELECT MAX(course_based_id) 
                  FROM courses_lessons 
                  WHERE cid = ?cid
                ), 0)
FROM
  dual ;
```

---

For this table, you don't really need the `id` column. A primary key on `(cid, lid)`  will be enough for identifying rows. You'll also need to add a unique key on `(cid, course_based_id)`:

```
ALTER TABLE courses_lessons 
  ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_cid_course_based_id
    UNIQUE cid_course_based_id_UQ
      (cid, course_based_id) ;
```

Comment: Won't it be susceptible to race conditions?

Comment: so it should be done with lock tables, ok. I've actually thought about creating a trigger emulating sequence on (cid, course_based_id). Using stored procedure is another good option.

Comment: Triggers have an issue with cascading effects, so that may not be an option.

Comment: `add a unique key on (cid, course_based_id)` please write query. I'm using visual db manager and haven't found anything related with uk.

Comment: I don't think so. Mixing cascading effects and triggers in InnoDB is not yet fixed I think.