# Isolation level for two statements on the same transaction vs. single statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, transactions, isolation-level

I have the following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event;
CREATE TABLE event(
    kind VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    num  INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE event ADD PRIMARY KEY (kind, num);
```

The idea is that I want to use the `num` column to maintain separate increment counters for each `kind` of event. So `num` is like a dedicated auto-increment sequence for each different `kind`.

Assuming multiple clients/threads writing events (potentially of the same `kind`) into that table concurrently, is there any difference in terms of the required level for transaction isolation between: (a) executing the following block:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    nextNum INTEGER;
BEGIN    
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(num),-1)+1 FROM event WHERE kind='A' INTO nextNum;
    INSERT INTO event(kind, num) VALUES('A', nextNum);
END;
$do$;
COMMIT;
```

... and (b) combining the `select` and `insert` into a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO event(kind, num)
(SELECT 'A', COALESCE(MAX(num),-1)+1 FROM event WHERE kind='A');
```

From some tests I run it seems that in both cases I need the `serializable` [transaction isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html). What's more, even with the `serializable` transactions isolation level, my code has to be prepared to retry due to the following error in highly concurrency situations:

```
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.
```

In other words merging the `select` into the `insert` does not seem to confer any benefit in terms of atomicity or allow any lower/more lenient transaction isolation level to be set. Am I missing anything?

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6369152/274677) is broadly related in that it asks for a PostgreSQL pattern to facilitate the generation of multiple sequences inside a table. So just to be clear I am not asking for the right pattern to do that sort of thing; I just want to understand if the block of two statements is in any way different than a single merged `INSERT`/`SELECT` statement).

Comment: I believe you are gaining nothing by going from the default isolation level (read committed) to serializable. You can wrap the whole thing in a begin try/catch and retry if it fails

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits I confirm after more testing that not only does the simpler `read committed` isolation level also work but that the `serializable` isolation level resulted in fact in many more retries being actually needed.

Comment: Thanks. By the way if test by doing your code without a commit and in another window try this: SELECT resource_type, resource_associated_entity_id,
    request_status, request_mode,request_session_id,
    resource_description 
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
and you will see all the locks currently in affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the task is possible concurrent write access. Merging `SELECT` and `INSERT` into one statement **reduces the time frame** for possible conflicts to a minimum and is the superior approach in any case. The potential for conflicts is still there. And yes, serializable transaction isolation is one possible (if expensive) solution.

Typically *(but that's not what you are asking)*, the best solution is *not to try* what you are trying. Gapless sequential numbers are a pain in databases with concurrent write access. If possible, use a `serial` column instead, which gives you unique ascending numbers - with possible gaps. You can eliminate gaps later or dynamically with in a `VIEW`. Details:

- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)

Aside: you don't need parentheses around the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO event(kind, num)
SELECT 'A', COALESCE(MAX(num) + 1, 0) FROM event WHERE kind='A';
```

Comment: I appreciated the insight about "gapless sequences" being a bad idea as none of the answers in the question I linked to had volunteered that perspective. Will definitely go that way on my next system.