# postgresql custom primarykey

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I try to make a project using hibernate and postgres as DB. The problem I have is I need to store the primary key as this 22/2017 or like 432/1990.

Let's say the first number is object_id and second year_added.

I think what I want to achieve is to make a first number and second number together a primary key so 22/2017 is different from 22/2016.
The only idea I have is when user add new object I generate current date year and trying to find last id and increment it.

So next year first added object should be : 1/2018.

So far in my db only object_id is  stored as a primary key.

Comment: Do you need to store the PK "as this", which is a String, or can you consider using a composite key with two integers?

Comment: Create a primary key with two integer columns

Comment: Yes composite key is what I ment.  So i need to decrlare a key id that autoincrement and year that is generates from insertion date?  How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work fine:
[PostgreSQL: Auto-increment based on multi-column unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369152/postgresql-auto-increment-based-on-multi-column-unique-constraint/6372052#6372052)

Thanks for helping me anyway.